How to make the title "Chapter 1" in class memoir sans-serif and `light_blue`?
I have a tex file
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=3
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\definecolor{light_blue}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \chapter style 
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily\color{light_blue}}% Set \subsection style

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
\chapter*{Abstract}

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=light_blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Motivation}
\section{Background}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some SDEs}
\subsection{Well-posedness of some PDEs}

\end{document}


The Title Chapter 1 is not formatted as sans-serif and not light_blue. Could you elaborate how to make it sans-serif and light_blue?

Update both \chapnamefont and \chapnumfont:
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{light_blue}}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{light_blue}}


The default is \normalfont\huge\bfseries, so I've just updated it to include \sffamily and \color{light_blue}.
